# Como modificar o documento HTML através de uma extensão?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extensão, firefox-extensão

Gostaria de fazer um botão aparecer no site que desenvolvi, mas só para quem tem a extensão.

Eu tenho os códigos CSS, HTML e Javascript pra gerar o botão. A funcionalidade do botão está pronta, só preciso fazer a extensão.

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: A extensao que voce quer identificar 'e sua ou de terceiros?

Comment: queria criar a minha própria extensão, as funcionalidades foram criadas por mim.

Comment: O que você já fez? Se vai criar a própria extensão, pode inserir o botão na página por meio da extensão.

Comment: Ja que a extensao 'e sua voce pode fazer ela se comunicar com a pagina atraves de uma troca de mensagens. Outro metodo seria voce fazer a sua extensao deixar algum rastro, como por exemplo adicionar uma classe a alguma tag usada na pagina.

Comment: já fiz todas as funcionalidades, são 2 botões com 2 input radios, todos estão funcionando. tem algum tutorial para seguir?

Answer (score 2):

### Extensão Chrome

1. Crie um diretório vazio o qual conterá os arquivos da extensão.
2. Crie nesse diretório o arquivo manifest.json.
3. Adicione ao diretório um arquivo JavaScript contendo o código que irá inserir o botão no final da página.
4. Adicione ao dreitório o arquivo de script do jQuery, que será usado pela extensão.

O **diretório representando a extensão** deverá ficar com o seguinte conteúdo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seu arquivo de manifesto deverá ficar da seguinte forma:

Arquivo **manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Adiciona Botao",
  "description": "Adiciona um botao no final da pagina",
  "version": "1.0",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "main.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

No arquivo **main.js** você executa o código que adiciona o botão:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").append("<input type='button' onclick='alert(\"Botão adicionado por uma extensão!\")' value='Botão Dinâmico' />");
});
```

Agora, para carregar a extensão, vá para a URL **chrome://extensions/**, clique em "Carregar Extensão Expandida..." e selecione a pasta da extensão.

Feito isso, basta acessar qualquer página que contenha http na URL e o botão será adicionado ao final dessa página. Clique no botão para testá-lo.

Answer (score 2):

Já há uma resposta sobre o desenvolvimento para Chrome, então tentarei explicar de forma simplificada como fazer o mesmo no Firefox.

A Mozilla disponibiliza um [**SDK**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) que inclui APIs para o desenvolvimento, execução e teste das extensões.

O desenvolvimento pode ser feito em qualquer editor de sua preferência, usando linguagens como Html, CSS e Javascript. Já a inicialização, execução e os testes são feitos por meio da [**jpm**](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jpm), que é uma ferramenta baseada em [**Node**](http://nodejs.org/) e que substituiu o uso do [**cfx**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/cfx) após o Firefox 38.

Na documentação da Mozilla, há [uma página](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm#Installation) voltada para a explicação de como instalar a *jpm*, bem como a lista dos comandos que podem ser usados como parâmetros de execução.

#### Iniciando

Tendo o *Node* e o módulo do *jpm* instalados, crie um diretório vazio.
Por linha de comando, navegue até o diretório que criou e execute o comando:

```
> jpm init
```

Serão perguntadas algumas informações como nome da extensão, descrição, autor... após inserir essas informações, no diretório, será criado um "esqueleto" como ponto de partida para o desenvolvimento.

Não é preciso fazer nenhuma modificação no [***package.json***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/package_json) por enquanto. E nem será necessário se a única coisa que precisa fazer é modificar o Html de uma página para criar um botão.

A única coisa que você precisa verificar é se o atributo `main` está apontado para o arquivo `index.js` que foi criado no diretório, ele define qual será o primeiro arquivo a ser executado.

#### Criando um botão na página 'x'

Um dos módulos no SDK é o [**page-mod**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) que, como o nome sugere, permite modificar páginas. Tomando como exemplo o StackOverflow, para inserir um botão na página, o `index.js` poderia ficar assim:

```
let { PageMod } = require('sdk/page-mod');

PageMod({
   include: '*.stackoverflow.com',
   contentScript: 'document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", "<button>Botão criado pela extensão</button>")'
});
```

Somente isto. Executando o comando `jpm run` e navegando até o site StackOverflow, o botão será exibido no topo da página:

[image: exemplo]

*No exemplo, o botão até herdou as regras CSS do site.*

Como você disse já ter o script que controla o botão, você pode trocar o `contentScript` por `contentScriptFile` para incluir o arquivo por completo.

No diretório da extensão, crie uma pasta chamada ***data*** e em qualquer módulo da extensão é possível usar o alias `./` para obter os arquivos na pasta *data*.

Então, em `minhaextensão/data/` você teria o seu arquivo Javascript que controla a interação com o botão. E agora seu `index.js` ficaria assim:

```
let { PageMod } = require('sdk/page-mod');

PageMod({
   include: '*.stackoverflow.com',
   contentScriptFile: './meuscript.js'
});
```

Se quiser importar mais de um script, também é possível:

```
let { PageMod } = require('sdk/page-mod');

PageMod({
   include: '*.stackoverflow.com',
   contentScriptFile: ['./jquery.min.js', './meuscript.js', './meuoutroscript.js']
});
```